# How to Publish/Export wxWidgets Application

Tags: codeblocks, wxwidgets, publish

newbie here.
Want to ask for any advice on how to Publish/Export, CodeBlocks Application made by using wxWidgets. After some research, i discovered that i should use DLL, or something like that, but since I am really new into it, I am missing the logic on how I should actually implement that. Since CodeBlocks offers wxWidgets and DLL as separate projects. So I am not really sure how to properly combine. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a little fuzzy on what you're really asking here? You can ship a wxWidgets built product in a variety of forms. Static or DLL both have their merits. Also you have the issue of platforms, architectures, etc. What have you tried? What are you attempting to achieve exactly?

Comment: Are you talking about a DLL that you have written or wxWidgets' DLL?

Comment: No I have  not wrote any DLL. I basically started an wxwidgets project, and then I simply run the default project to check if I manage to configure everything as i should about the wxwidgets. The run was working within the CodeBlocks and it did showed me empty window in preview Mode.

Comment: But when i get into the project directory and try to run the file that is Application type it shows me this error: **The program cant start because wxbase28d_gcc.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling to fix this problem.**  I am a newbie with c++, and just wanted, to see how does it looks to actually build real program without the console examples. I use win7 32bit

Answer (score 0):

If you used wxWidgets as .dll, to get a self-standing package you have to distribute all the requested libraries. The simplest way is just to copy them from their source folder (in your case `[wxWidgets root]\lib\gcc_dll`) in the same folder as your executable. There could be many of them, but usually only two or three are needed. For simplicity you can copy them all, or you can try repeatedly to start the program, and add each time the library indicated in the error message.

Please note that to distribute your application you will probably want to compile it in Release mode, and consequently you should ship the Release .dlls (i.e. beginning with `wx...28_` instead of `wx...28d_`).